# How to divide a HTML website into 3, individually scrollable divs?

Tags: css, html

So I am trying to make a website that is divided into 3 columns that you can scroll down on each one individually.

I have tried making them and just making them 33% width but whenever I add something I get a weird chunk at the bottom of the screen and I can't scroll in them by themselves.

Sorry if this does not make sense.

Comment: _“Sorry if this does not make sense.”_ - go read up on how to make some: [ask] & [mcve].

Comment: make those dives fill the view-port vertically by using 100vh, assign 100vh to body as well then hide overflow of the body, It is always better to share your code

Comment: Looks like **flexbox** is what you need. Try learning how to use it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't quite understand what you mean by "weird chunk", but it might be margin/padding from the html oder body elements.

Here's a working example using `overflow: auto` on the columns. I used 33.33% width to hack it together quickly, but you'd probably want to use proper flex-attributes to justify content evenly and add margins in between.

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
}

body {
  display: flex;
}

.col {
  overflow: auto;
  max-height: 100vh;
  width: 33.33%;
}
```

```html
<section class="col">
Some very lenghy content...<br>
Some very lenghy content...<br>
Some very lenghy content...<br>
Some very lenghy content...<br>
Some very lenghy content...<br>
Some very lenghy content...<br>
Some very lenghy content...<br>
Some very lenghy content...<br>
Some very lenghy content...<br>
Some very lenghy content...<br>
Some very lenghy content...<br>
Some very lenghy content...<br>
Some very lenghy content...<br>
Some very lenghy content...<br>
Some very lenghy content...<br>
Some very lenghy content...<br>
Some very lenghy content...<br>
Some very lenghy content...<br>
Some very lenghy content...<br>
Some very lenghy content...<br>
Some very lenghy content...<br>
Some very lenghy content...<br>
Some very lenghy content...<br>
Some very lenghy content...<br>
Some very lenghy content...<br>
Some very lenghy content...<br>
Some very lenghy content...<br>
Some very lenghy content...<br>
Some very lenghy content...<br>
Some very lenghy content...<br>
Some very lenghy content...<br>
Some very lenghy content...<br>
Some very lenghy content...<br>
Some very lenghy content...<br>
Some very lenghy content...<br>
Some very lenghy content...<br>
Some very lenghy content...<br>
Some very lenghy content...<br>
Some very lenghy content...<br>
Some very lenghy content...<br>
Some very lenghy content...<br>
Some very lenghy content...<br>
Some very lenghy content...<br>
Some very lenghy content...<br>
Some very lenghy content...<br>
Some very lenghy content...<br>
Some very lenghy content...<br>
Some very lenghy content...
</section>
<section class="col">
Some very lenghy content...<br>
Some very lenghy content...<br>
Some very lenghy content...<br>
Some very lenghy content...<br>
Some very lenghy content...<br>
Some very lenghy content...<br>
Some very lenghy content...<br>
Some very lenghy content...<br>
Some very lenghy content...<br>
Some very lenghy content...<br>
Some very lenghy content...<br>
Some very lenghy content...<br>
Some very lenghy content...<br>
Some very lenghy content...<br>
Some very lenghy content...<br>
Some very lenghy content...<br>
Some very lenghy content...<br>
Some very lenghy content...<br>
Some very lenghy content...<br>
Some very lenghy content...<br>
Some very lenghy content...<br>
Some very lenghy content...<br>
Some very lenghy content...<br>
Some very lenghy content...<br>

Some very lenghy content...<br>
Some very lenghy content...<br>
Some very lenghy content...<br>
Some very lenghy content...<br>
Some very lenghy content...<br>
Some very lenghy content...<br>
Some very lenghy content...<br>
Some very lenghy content...<br>
Some very lenghy content...<br>
Some very lenghy content...<br>
Some very lenghy content...<br>
Some very lenghy content...<br>
Some very lenghy content...<br>
Some very lenghy content...<br>
Some very lenghy content...<br>
Some very lenghy content...<br>
Some very lenghy content...<br>
Some very lenghy content...<br>
Some very lenghy content...<br>
Some very lenghy content...<br>
Some very lenghy content...<br>
Some very lenghy content...<br>
Some very lenghy content...<br>
Some very lenghy content...
</section>
<section class="col">
Some very lenghy content...<br>
Some very lenghy content...<br>
Some very lenghy content...<br>
Some very lenghy content...<br>
Some very lenghy content...<br>
Some very lenghy content...<br>
Some very lenghy content...<br>
Some very lenghy content...<br>
Some very lenghy content...<br>
Some very lenghy content...<br>
Some very lenghy content...<br>
Some very lenghy content...<br>
Some very lenghy content...<br>
Some very lenghy content...<br>
Some very lenghy content...<br>
Some very lenghy content...<br>
Some very lenghy content...<br>
Some very lenghy content...<br>
Some very lenghy content...<br>
Some very lenghy content...<br>
Some very lenghy content...<br>
Some very lenghy content...<br>
Some very lenghy content...<br>
Some very lenghy content...<br>

Some very lenghy content...<br>
Some very lenghy content...<br>
Some very lenghy content...<br>
Some very lenghy content...<br>
Some very lenghy content...<br>
Some very lenghy content...<br>
Some very lenghy content...<br>
Some very lenghy content...<br>
Some very lenghy content...<br>
Some very lenghy content...<br>
Some very lenghy content...<br>
Some very lenghy content...<br>
Some very lenghy content...<br>
Some very lenghy content...<br>
Some very lenghy content...<br>
Some very lenghy content...<br>
Some very lenghy content...<br>
Some very lenghy content...<br>
Some very lenghy content...<br>
Some very lenghy content...<br>
Some very lenghy content...<br>
Some very lenghy content...<br>
Some very lenghy content...<br>
Some very lenghy content...
</section>
```

Comment: I would add overflow: hidden to the body as well just to be safe but this is pretty much it.

Comment: Thought about that as well and you could do it just to be safe. But this should work as it is in major browsers. For older browsers you'd also need to make changes for flex and the vh unit used in the example,

Answer (score 1):

Or with CSS `grid`

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
}

body {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
}

.col {
  grid-column: 1 1;
  overflow: auto;
  max-height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<section class="col">
Some very lenghy content...<br>
Some very lenghy content...<br>
Some very lenghy content...<br>
Some very lenghy content...<br>
Some very lenghy content...<br>
Some very lenghy content...<br>
Some very lenghy content...<br>
Some very lenghy content...<br>
Some very lenghy content...<br>
Some very lenghy content...<br>
Some very lenghy content...<br>
Some very lenghy content...<br>
Some very lenghy content...<br>
Some very lenghy content...<br>
Some very lenghy content...<br>
Some very lenghy content...<br>
Some very lenghy content...<br>
Some very lenghy content...<br>
Some very lenghy content...<br>
Some very lenghy content...<br>
Some very lenghy content...<br>
Some very lenghy content...<br>
Some very lenghy content...<br>
Some very lenghy content...<br>
Some very lenghy content...<br>
Some very lenghy content...<br>
Some very lenghy content...<br>
Some very lenghy content...<br>
Some very lenghy content...<br>
Some very lenghy content...<br>
Some very lenghy content...<br>
Some very lenghy content...<br>
Some very lenghy content...<br>
Some very lenghy content...<br>
Some very lenghy content...<br>
Some very lenghy content...<br>
Some very lenghy content...<br>
Some very lenghy content...<br>
Some very lenghy content...<br>
Some very lenghy content...<br>
Some very lenghy content...<br>
Some very lenghy content...<br>
Some very lenghy content...<br>
Some very lenghy content...<br>
Some very lenghy content...<br>
Some very lenghy content...<br>
Some very lenghy content...<br>
Some very lenghy content...
</section>
<section class="col">
Some very lenghy content...<br>
Some very lenghy content...<br>
Some very lenghy content...<br>
Some very lenghy content...<br>
Some very lenghy content...<br>
Some very lenghy content...<br>
Some very lenghy content...<br>
Some very lenghy content...<br>
Some very lenghy content...<br>
Some very lenghy content...<br>
Some very lenghy content...<br>
Some very lenghy content...<br>
Some very lenghy content...<br>
Some very lenghy content...<br>
Some very lenghy content...<br>
Some very lenghy content...<br>
Some very lenghy content...<br>
Some very lenghy content...<br>
Some very lenghy content...<br>
Some very lenghy content...<br>
Some very lenghy content...<br>
Some very lenghy content...<br>
Some very lenghy content...<br>
Some very lenghy content...<br>

Some very lenghy content...<br>
Some very lenghy content...<br>
Some very lenghy content...<br>
Some very lenghy content...<br>
Some very lenghy content...<br>
Some very lenghy content...<br>
Some very lenghy content...<br>
Some very lenghy content...<br>
Some very lenghy content...<br>
Some very lenghy content...<br>
Some very lenghy content...<br>
Some very lenghy content...<br>
Some very lenghy content...<br>
Some very lenghy content...<br>
Some very lenghy content...<br>
Some very lenghy content...<br>
Some very lenghy content...<br>
Some very lenghy content...<br>
Some very lenghy content...<br>
Some very lenghy content...<br>
Some very lenghy content...<br>
Some very lenghy content...<br>
Some very lenghy content...<br>
Some very lenghy content...
</section>
<section class="col">
Some very lenghy content...<br>
Some very lenghy content...<br>
Some very lenghy content...<br>
Some very lenghy content...<br>
Some very lenghy content...<br>
Some very lenghy content...<br>
Some very lenghy content...<br>
Some very lenghy content...<br>
Some very lenghy content...<br>
Some very lenghy content...<br>
Some very lenghy content...<br>
Some very lenghy content...<br>
Some very lenghy content...<br>
Some very lenghy content...<br>
Some very lenghy content...<br>
Some very lenghy content...<br>
Some very lenghy content...<br>
Some very lenghy content...<br>
Some very lenghy content...<br>
Some very lenghy content...<br>
Some very lenghy content...<br>
Some very lenghy content...<br>
Some very lenghy content...<br>
Some very lenghy content...<br>

Some very lenghy content...<br>
Some very lenghy content...<br>
Some very lenghy content...<br>
Some very lenghy content...<br>
Some very lenghy content...<br>
Some very lenghy content...<br>
Some very lenghy content...<br>
Some very lenghy content...<br>
Some very lenghy content...<br>
Some very lenghy content...<br>
Some very lenghy content...<br>
Some very lenghy content...<br>
Some very lenghy content...<br>
Some very lenghy content...<br>
Some very lenghy content...<br>
Some very lenghy content...<br>
Some very lenghy content...<br>
Some very lenghy content...<br>
Some very lenghy content...<br>
Some very lenghy content...<br>
Some very lenghy content...<br>
Some very lenghy content...<br>
Some very lenghy content...<br>
Some very lenghy content...
</section>
```